# Poisson Kernel and solution formula for fractional elliptic problem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, fractional-calculus

$$
k (-\Delta)^s u +   u = 0, \qquad x \in U, \\
u(x) = f(x), \qquad x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus U,
$$
with $f \in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$, $k>0$, and $(-\Delta)^s$ is the [singular integral fractional Laplacian](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Fractional_Laplacian?#As_a_singular_integral).

Does a representation formula like
$$u(x) = c_{n,s}\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus \overline U }  f(z) \int_U\int_0^\infty e^{- t/k} p_U^t(x, y) |y - z|^{-N-2s}d t  d y d z, $$
hold for the solution? Here $p^t_U$ denotes the fractional heat kernel.

If yes, what kind of solution is it (classical, weak, viscosity,...)?